# Load data to dynamic row Cell

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to load MySQL table field data to dynamic insert row field cell. but don't know how to do this without Ajax. Your advice may help to complete this task.

```js
var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
        var el = document.createElement('input');
  el.type = 'text';
        el.name = 'SL' + iteration;
        el.id = 'SL' + iteration;
        el.size = 5;
  cellLeft.appendChild(el);

       // var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
        //cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

        // right cell
   var cellRight = row.insertCell(1);
        var eel = document.createElement('input');
  eel.type = 'text';
        eel.name = 'STYLE' + iteration;
        eel.id = 'STYLE' + iteration;
        eel.size = 15
        cellRight.appendChild(eel);
  
  var cellRight2 = row.insertCell(2);
        var eel = document.createElement('input');
  eel.type = 'text';
        eel.name = 'PROD_REF' + iteration;
        eel.id = 'PROD_REF' + iteration;
  eel.size = 15
        cellRight2.appendChild(eel);
  
  
  var cellRight3 = row.insertCell(3);
        var eel = document.createElement('input');
  eel.type = 'text';
        eel.name = 'OUR_REF' + iteration;
        eel.id = 'OUR_REF' + iteration;
        eel.size = 15
        cellRight3.appendChild(eel);
  
        var cellRight4 = row.insertCell(4);
        var eel = document.createElement('textarea');
  eel.type = 'text';
        eel.name = 'ITEM_DESC' + iteration;
        eel.id = 'ITEM_DESC' + iteration;
        eel.size = 10
        cellRight4.appendChild(eel);

        var cellRight5 = row.insertCell(5);
        var el = document.createElement('input');
        el.type = 'text';
        el.name = 'QTY' + iteration;
        el.id = 'QTY' + iteration;
        el.setAttribute('class', 'QTY');
        el.onblur = function() { productcalc(); };
        el.class = 'QTY'
        el.size = 10;
        cellRight5.appendChild(el);

        var cellRight6 = row.insertCell(6);
        var el = document.createElement('input');
        el.type = 'text';
        el.setAttribute('class', 'PRICE');
        el.onblur = function() { productcalc(); };
        el.name = 'PRICE' + iteration;
        el.id = 'PRICE' + iteration;
        el.size = 10;
        cellRight6.appendChild(el);

        var cellRight7 = row.insertCell(7);
        var el = document.createElement('input');
        el.type = 'text';
        el.name = 'AMOUNT' + iteration;
        el.setAttribute('class', 'AMOUNT');
        el.onblur = function() { productcalc(); };
        el.class = 'AMOUNT'
        el.id = 'AMOUNT';
        el.size = 10;
        cellRight7.appendChild(el);
```

here is my PHP code of first line. then want to insert dynamic row

```html
<tbody>
            <tr>
           
                <td><input readonly name="SL"id="SL" value="1" size='5' /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="STYLE" class="STYLE" id="STYLE" size='15' /></td>
                <td><?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('aaa');

$sql = "SELECT Code FROM label_entry ORDER BY Code ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='PROD_REF' class='PROD_REF' id='PROD_REF' STYLE='width: 120px'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Code'] . "'>" . $row['Code'] . "</option>";
} 
echo "</select>";

?></td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="OUR_REF" class="OUR_REF" id="OUR_REF" size='15' /></td>
                
                <td><textarea name="ITEM_DESC" id="ITEM_DESC" cols="20" rows="1" maxlength="300"></textarea></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="QTY" class="QTY" id="QTY" onBlur="productcalc()" size='10' /></td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name="PRICE" class="PRICE" id="PRICE" onBlur="productcalc()" size='10' />
                    
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="AMOUNT" class="AMOUNT" onBlur="productcalc()" id="AMOUNT" size='10' /></td>
                               
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Where is the `mysql` and `php` part of the code?

Comment: without ajax .. use iframe then